# Hibernate - How to map java Pair<> object

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

How can I use Hibenate to map Pair to 2 different columns in a SQL table?

For example, if I have this class:

```
public class Example {
    private int a;
    private Pair<Double, Double> b;
}
```

And I want to map it to a table with 3 columns:

1. a
2. b1
3. b2

What is the best way to do that?

I tried to create custom type and use the @Type annotation but I couldn't figure out which implementation of SqlTypeDescriptor interface is suitable for this case.

Comment: Did you figure it out?